# What is the pressure apllied to liquid in sealed tank?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, pressure, conventions

I have a sealed tank positioned on a high surface filled with water and nitrogen gas above. Tank manometre shows pressure of 0.5 bar.
What is the pressure applied to the water in tank? Is it 0.5 or 1.5 bar?

Comment: Is the manometer 'gauge' or 'absolute'? 'Gauge' is relative to the environment, 'absolute' is, well, absolute.

Comment: The manometer is indicating gauge pressure so the 0.5 bars is probably gauge. The absolute pressure is probably 1.5 bars.

Answer (score 0):

Indicated gauge pressure ( relative to outside ) acts both on air and water.

Both are fluids obeying Pascal's Law with a uniform pressurized state.